# How to skip empty page in pagination endlessRecyclerView?

Tags: android, pagination

In Pagination functionality, if data is not getting for one of page then pagination stops their instead of continue with next page.

Comment: Try checking list size if 0 or the same as previous list size  then can make currentpage+1 maybe that way

Comment: I used EndlessScrollListener.